# Is it harmful to have irrelevant xmlns attributes in a sitemap urlset element?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

For example, if a site has absolutely no videos and is not a news site, is there any negative (or positive) impact to having a sitemap urlset element like this:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
[all site page URLS here]

enter code here
```

Is there any authoritative source which might help shed some light on this?

Comment: Side note: all these xmlns:* attributes are the default output when using this NPM package: https://github.com/ekalinin/sitemap.js

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any "authoritative source" from which to quote, but all you are doing here is declaring additional namespaces that could potentially be used in the rest of the file. By themselves, they don't actually do anything.

Assuming you are not also creating bogus `<video:video>` or `<news:publication>` etc. entries in the sitemap data then I fail see how simply declaring the namespaces will have any impact at all, positive or negative, except for possibly increasing the file size an itsy bitsy amount.

Comment: Thanks for the input (and for the edits to the question). I tend to believe you... I would just like to hear it from Google or Bing or Moz.com or searchengineland or similar.

Comment: From a practical standpoint you could submit a sitemap like this to Google Search Console and see if it gets parsed properly and the expected reports generated.